# CakePHP: provide alternative view formats?

Tags: templates, cakephp, view

I currently have one view that I would like to split up into many different formats, each with a different ctp.  I'm looking to provide the page formatted specifically for certain devices, with a template for each of PC, Kindle, iPhone, etc.

Is there a canonical way of switching between views like this?  The URL should be different for each so that I can bookmark the Kindle version and view it on a PC if I want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample code I used in a project to automatically render alternative view files based on the current language. This allows you to save views as `/views/[controller]/[lang]/[action].ctp`. If such a specialized file exists, it will be rendered instead of the standard view. This should be easily adaptable to your needs.

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function render($action = null, $layout = null, $file = null) {
        $lang = Configure::read('Config.language');
        $ext = $this->ext;
        $act = $action;
        if (!$act) {
            $act = $this->action;
        }

        $i18nFile = new File(VIEWS . $this->viewPath . DS . $lang . DS . $act . $ext);
        if (!$file && $i18nFile->exists()) {
            $file = $i18nFile->path;
        }

        return parent::render($action, $layout, $file);
    }
}
```